# Problems replacing &ldquo; in a string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to replace `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` in C#, they're in the middle of the data I get from an API call.
I want to replace them to my "key", but when I do

```
response = response.Replace("&ldquo;", "$QUOT");
response = response.Replace("&rdquo;", "$QUOT");
```

It doesn't actually replace anything.
I need to display this data later and be able to process it with XmlReader, but it throws an exception when it sees ldquo in the stream I pass to it.
Any ideas?

It's literally just a string that holds the response from HttpClient's get for a custom API. It's just some XML. It's not a property.

It is in the string, I've checked multiple times. It never gets replaced.

Comment: Could you provide a *test sample*?

Comment: is response just a string? is it a property?

Comment: It's possible that the &ldquo; string is actually encoded as &amp;ldquo; Same for the &rdquo; but appears to be &ldquo/&rdquo

Comment: If it doesn't replace anything then that means `"&ldquo;"` wasn't found in the string.

Comment: Aside: don't you want to keep the `;` in the result?

Comment: See following webpages : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML, If you are using .NET 4.0+ you can also use WebUtility.HtmlDecode which does not require an extra assembly reference as it is available in the System.Net namespace.

Comment: @HaukurHaf Will check this and report back.

Comment: @HaukurHaf That was it. If you would be so kind to put this up as an answer so I could accept it to help other people with the same issue?

Comment: Nice, just posted an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the `&ldquo;` string is actually encoded as `&amp;ldquo;` Same for the `&rdquo;` but they might still appear to be just `&ldquo/&rdquo`